# CalloutAccessoryTapped - Why won't a web address open? something simple im sure

Tags: swift, button, annotations, inputaccessoryview

So I'm playing around with `MKAnnotationView` and I have a right `calloutaccessory`.

Since I only have one annotation, I figured I'd try to make this as simple as possible with a webpage being opened - google. However, it is not and I don't understand why.  What am I missing?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        let url = NSURL(string: "google.com")
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as! URL)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use complete url to open google page. Try this:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not `canOpenURL` it used for checking that app is able to open url or not

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether or not the URL’s scheme can be handled by some app installed on the device.

From **iOS 10 *** it is `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)` and else you can use

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

According to docs

> Important
>
> If your app is linked on or after iOS 9.0, you must declare the URL schemes you want to pass to this method. Do this by adding the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key to your app's Info.plist file. If you call this method for a scheme not declared using that key, this method always returns false, whether or not an appropriate app is installed. To learn more about the key, see LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

Comment: While my mistake (thank you for the catch), even if i have a print statement, it does not show up in the console, meaning the code did not run. Ideas?

Comment: @jonpeter You are most welcome brother , Don't forgot to add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` otherwise your `canOpenURL` will always return false , You can accept answer if it is helpful